# Querying MySQL DB with .NET Standard 1.4 or 1.5

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, .net-core, .net-standard

I am trying to create a single library that can be used by a WPF project and a .NET Core project.

I need to connect to a MySQL database. MySQL.Data requires .NET Standard 1.6, but there is no .NET Framework for .NET Standard 1.6 (4.6.2 only uses 1.5).

What are the options for connecting to a MySQL database using .NET Standard 1.5?(until .NET Standard 2.0 comes out and can be used with 4.6.1)

Comment: I've been researching this question not very long ago. There are no options yet. You can user .NET Core or regular .NET application, but not .NET Standard.

Answer (score 2):

All these MySQL data providers depend on `.NET Standard 1.3`:

[MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector)

[Pomelo.Data.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.Data.MySql)

[Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)